# How to use dispatch in createSlice reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

For example i have this slice and I want to use dispatch in setUser. How can I do this?

```
const contactsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'contacts',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUsers: (state, { payload }) => {
      // I want to use dispatch here
      dispatch()
    },
    toggleFavorite: (state, { payload }) => {
      //
    },
    toggleCheck: (state, { payload }) => {
      //
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't, you implementing a reducer where `dispatch` function is not available. Read what [reducers are](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers).

Instead, add the logic in React code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(contactsSlice.actions.setUser());
  dispatch(loginSlice.actions.logicAction());
}, []);
```

Or, add an extra reducer in the **target slice**.

```
const contactsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "contacts",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUsers: (state, { payload }) => {
      // setUsers logic
    },
  },
});

const loginSlice = createSlice({
  name: "login",
  initialState: initialState,
  extraReducers: {
    "contacts/setUsers": (state, { payload }) => {
      // Same logic
    },
  },
});
```

Or write a middleware, like [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#createasyncthunk), `dispatch` and `getState` functions available under `thunkAPI`.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your store to window,

```
window.store = store
```

after that you can call dispatch in a setTimeout function

```
setTimeout(() => {
    window.store.dispatch(...)
})
```